# How can change name of project and package?

Tags: android, json, eclipse

I am developing an Android application named "English SMS Collection" in Google Play store, and now I want to upload this app in Hindi language also. So what changes are required to previous APK?
How to add another language to an Android application? And also what image size icons are required for uploading the app to market?

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: change the package name. probably you can add ".hindhi" to the package name. Make the change in AndroidManifest.xml also. Then this will be come a separate new application.  Poejct name or apk name will never be considered by market. But i think the better option is to use settings page where you can give option to the user to select the language. In sqlite save these changes and also put the URLs for the respective languages. Depending on the language you can carry out the task.

Comment: thank u but \how can chage name of package?

Comment: do it in eclipse. right click on package and change the name.

Comment: after change my name of package ..app forseclose?'

Comment: probably you have not changed the packages at all the places. may be some where for launching activity or for calling service, you have the old package name. put the error here.

Comment: change the package name in manifest file too

Comment: If you get a ForceClose, post your stack trace, otherwise no one will be able to help you

Answer (score 1):

Generally, splitting the same app into two functionally equivalent versions with different languages is a bad idea.

If you absolutely must do that, the only thing you need to change is the package name (`package="com.example.project"`) in your AndroidManifest.xml (no need to rename actual packages, just that one string in manifest).

Also, if your Activities are declared relatively to app's package (e.g. `.MyActivity` as opposed to `com.mypackage.activities.MyActivity`) - and they most likely are - changing app's package name will obviously cause FCs because you effectively rename the activities. So to be able to switch the package name back and forth you'll have to detach Activity names from app's package by declaring them absolutely (e.g. `com.mypackage.activities.MyActivity`)

Here's a comprehensive guide on icons from Google, next time please do more research before asking such simple questions: [Iconography](http://developer.android.com/design/style/iconography.html)

Also, judging by the question, you'll probably want to also read into this: [Publishing Checklist for Google Play](http://developer.android.com/distribute/googleplay/publish/preparing.html)

Answer (score 1):

Please DO NOT split your app up into two apks just because of the language. This is very bad style.

According to the android devleoper's guide, it's best practice to create ressource-folders with so called "configuration qualifiers". Your strings (e.g. text) should all be stored in the file /res/values/strings.xml . This is the default setup (without a configuration qualifier), when adding localized translations you have to create a new folder and strings.xml file /res/values-**cc**/strings.xml where **cc** has to be the standardized country/language code (e.g. "en" for english, "de" for german, "cs" for czech...).

For more (essential) informations on this, visit developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/localization.html .

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the `package name` because it should be unique while uploading in `market`. It can be signed with the same `keystore` file you have done for other two apps. Obviously, you have to change the Application `name` and its `icon`.

For more Information on Publishing Checklist for Android Apps, [check this documentation](http://developer.android.com/intl/ja/distribute/googleplay/publish/preparing.html).

Comment: can u pls tel how can change name package?

Comment: I dont know which IDE u r using... but if you r using Eclipse, right click on the package and refactor->rename and then change the package name in AndroidManifest.xml. Then change the package names in all the classes as well.

Comment: am using Eclipse...after change name of package and manifestfile..string file also give same or else?

Comment: You are getting FORCE CLOSE because You need to change the package name in AndroidManifest.xml and all the .java files(having package name on top of the file) and where you placed the package name as a string(suppose in strings.xml/hard-coded anywhere in java classes) AFTER renaming the package.....

Comment: Desc = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.description); geting error

Comment: Clean the project once and build the application

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/25758/discussion-between-areddy-and-avaphaui)

Answer (score 0):

In a Package Explorer, click on the package name (e.g: com.example.android), right-click and go to Refactor. Choose the Rename... option there.